# preserve cursor position when changing innerHTML in a contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm building an Editor that does syntax highlighting on code. My current approach is to just take the text in the editor (a div with contenteditable set to true) and check for regex matches in the string. I then replace the matches with `<span>` elements and apply some styles to those span elements. Then I replace the complete text in the divider with the new text using the `.innerHTML` attribute. This works just fine, but I have to type backwards, because upon inserting the text, my cursor is reset to position zero. I tried recording the value of `selectionStart` before inserting and then doing

```js
element.selectionStart = oldSelectionStart + 1;
```

but it didn't work. I assume this is because of chrome's render pipeline, where JavaScript is run before rendering the page, and the cursor is reset upon render, not upon set... Can anyone help? How do I manage to keep the cursor where it was?

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/jqueryhtml5-input-focus-cursor-positions/ in fact https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/move-cursor-to-end-of-input/

Comment: @PabloRecalde it *is* focused, and I've tried literally everything to change the cursor position, it just keeps reverting it to the beginning

Comment: Then maybe the problem is about the order things happen, be sure all your new content is in place before you try to move the cursor.

Comment: Also https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-set-cursor-position-in-content-editable-element-using-javascript/

Comment: @PabloRecalde Yea, turns out theres even more s**t: It is set, and javascript also notices that, you can try ```document.body.innerHTML = "lol"; alert(document.body.innerHTML)```, and the value acctually changes, before the rendering, which I think is the problem

Comment: @Jake did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

`element.selectionStart` works for input elements, not for `contentEditable` elements.  You should try creating a `Range` object, set its `startContainer` & `startOffset` and collapse it to set caret at the required position. Refer to [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range] for details.

PS: If you would like to set your cursor to the 'end of line', you could do it easily with `range.selectNode(requiredNode)` and `range.collapse(true)` to move the caret to the end of node, i.e., line